# Access denied when deleting folders created in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, directory, xp-cmdshell

I am creating directories with xp_cmdshell but I can't delete them after because of the permission, I am not even allowed to see the owner of the folders.
I have to enter in safe mode to be able of delete the folders.
I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Danger, Will Robinson, Danger!

This sounds like it might not be ideal from several angles - security, future-proofing, and scalability. Assuming none of those are priorities for your code, crack on with Edgard's answer.

Otherwise, I would question any design that has the DBMS (directly) write folders in the file system. I don't question that you have your reasons, it's just that there are some very big, but very non-obvious risks that won't bite you until later when you're already committed to the course. There may be less risky and more straightforward ways to do whatever you're doing.

Comment: I am working with Paradox tables and I need to copy the content on a SQL table, the tables are locked by the lck files so I can't execute an openrowset and I thougth that I could make a copy from the tables and then execute the openrowset but then I realized that I can't remove a folder created by the SQL procedure. I will try to find another solution less risky.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it's an ACL problem.

A directory created with `xp_cmdshell` is owned by SQL Server (The service account) and its access rights are inherited from the parent.

If you have to modify the directory's content after its creation, you'll have to :

- Create your directory inside another one who already have *good* access rights.
- Or grant more rights after its creation (with `xp_cmdshell` and `icacls` to manipulate the ACLs)

Eg, change `domain\group` & `d:\folder_path` in the following snippet to whatever suits you to give a group (your users, admins, etc...) full control on a directory :

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'icacls "d:\folder_path" /grant "domain\group":(f)'
```